# How to store unique function name in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I was working on my code and wanting to figure out how i can store draggable objects into an array because I am creating a math game that will recognize the draggable element and determine whether the problem is correct which is addition  here is my code

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#draggable1" ).draggable();
        });
  </script>
 <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#draggable2" ).draggable();
        });
  </script>
 <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#draggable3" ).draggable();
        });
  </script>
 <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#draggable4" ).draggable();
        });
  </script>
 <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#draggable5" ).draggable();
        });
  </script>
 <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#draggable6" ).draggable();
        });
  </script>
 <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#draggable7" ).draggable();
        });
  </script>
 <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#draggable8" ).draggable();
        });
  </script>
```

and then i am trying to put these draggable elements into an array

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<script>
var theimagestwo = new Array();
theimagestwo[1] = "#draggable1";
theimagestwo[2] = "#draggable2";
document.getElementById("pagethree").innerHTML = theimagestwo[1];
</script>
```

what am i doing wrong? they are just coming up as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this part of your code (I added comments):

```
// Create a new array
var theimagestwo = new Array();

// Push the strings "#draggable1" and "#draggable2" into the array
theimagestwo[1] = "#draggable1";
theimagestwo[2] = "#draggable2";

// Set inner HTML as theimagestwo[1] (which is "#draggable1")
document.getElementById("pagethree").innerHTML = theimagestwo[1];
```

So, as you say, the result is "coming up as text" because it is text.

If I understand you correctly you want the contents of #pagethree to be the **element** #draggable1 (and not the **string** `"#draggable1"`). So you should replace the code above with:

```
var theimagestwo = new Array();
theimagestwo[1] = $("#draggable1");
theimagestwo[2] = $("#draggable2");
$("#pagethree").empty().append(theimagestwo[1]);
```

Comment: awesome this worked , what if i wanted to write multiple html files for example if i do  $("#pagethree").empty().append(theimagestwo[1]); and $("#pagethree").empty().append(theimagestwo[2]); it only displays one of them

Comment: @artbarzz you just `empty()` the element once and after that you `append()` as many child elements as you want..

Comment: Why would you ever want to use `new Array()` constructor instead of  `[]`

Answer (score 1):

you can create a function for that  and loop through using `.each()`

```
$('[id^="draggable"]').each(function(){ // [id^="draggable"] mean select all elements there ids starts with draggable
    makeItDraggaple($(this));
});


function makeItDraggaple(el){
    el.draggable();
    $("#pagethree").append(el);
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/qcn6roxe/4/)

or you can use just use **.each()** without need a function

```
$('[id^="draggable"]').each(function(){ // [id^="draggable"] mean select all elements there ids starts with draggable
     $(this).draggable();
     $("#pagethree").append($(this));
 });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/qcn6roxe/2/)

Comment: I don't get it can you provide fiddle please?

Comment: @artbarzz updated answer with demo .. now all ids start with draggable is draggable

Answer (score 0):

On top of the answer from @Mohamed-Yousef, if you're looking to place all these elements in the "pagethree" container, you can probably do that by adding one line:

```
$('[id^="draggable"]').each(function(){
    makeItDraggaple($(this));
    $(this).appendTo("#pagethree");
});
```

There are some inefficiencies in doing `$(this)` twice and likely in not caching `$("#pagethree")` somewhere.  But it's an (untested!) start.